# How to add a scene panning using mouse drag event OpenGL( with perspective projection)?

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, glut, freeglut, glu

Is there to have a scene panning (kind of like we get in gmaps) with simple mouse event ? Currently I two mouse events :

1. Mousewheel to zoom by changing `cRadius` in `glTranslatef`
2. LMB dragging for rotation by changing `xrot` and `yrot` in `glRotatef`.

   Below is the function:

```cpp
float xpos = 0, ypos = 0, zpos = 0, xrot = 0, yrot = 0, zrot = 0, cRadius = 30.0f, lastx, lasty, lastz;

void mouseMovement(int x, int y)
{
    int diffx = x - lastx; 
    int diffy = y - lasty; 
    lastx = x;             
    lasty = y;  
    
    xrot += (float)diffy;  
    yrot += (float)diffx; 
}
```

and mouse button initialization function below

```cpp
void mouseFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
{
    lastx = x;
    lasty = y;
}
```

Can the pan function be enabled using the same logic that is being used for rotation, like replacing **`xrot`** and **`yrot`** with a different variable in `glTranslatef` (if not where should be the translation applied) ? Below is my display function along with reshape function. Am using `glPerspective` rather that `glLookat`

```cpp
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -cRadius);
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_LINES);      
      ------------
      ------
    glTranslated(-xpos, 0.0f, zpos);
    glutSwapBuffers();              
    glEnd();
}
```

The mouse functions has been called in main loop

```cpp
int OpenGL(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseFunc);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMovement);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

//Reshape

```cpp
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.1, 500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: At perspective projection panning depends on the depth of the object. Related: [Qmatrix4x4 translate does not take any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491410/qmatrix4x4-translate-does-not-take-any-effect/54491988#54491988)

Comment: I went through the link but i couldn't figure out how I could implement that in my code. As you can see, my current mouse functions doesn't have any buttons or state defined(GLUT_UP or GLUT_DOWN). As of now both my LMB and RMB is doing the same thing. Can gltranslatef be made varying according to mouse? Am using the same for 'zoom' with  glutMouseWheelFunc , by changing cRadius in gltranslatef (under display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At perspective projection panning depends on the depth of the object. (See [Qmatrix4x4 translate does not take any effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491410/qmatrix4x4-translate-does-not-take-any-effect/54491988#54491988).
Luckily you know the dept of the geometry. It is defined in view space by `cRadius`.

The relation between the projected area in view space and the Z coordinate of the view space is linear. It depends on the field of view angle and the aspect ratio.
(See also [Field of view + Aspect Ratio + View Matrix from Projection Matrix (HMD OST Calibration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182845/field-of-view-aspect-ratio-view-matrix-from-projection-matrix-hmd-ost-calib/46195462#46195462))

[image]

A projected size in normalized device space can be transformed to a size in view space by:

```cpp
aspect = w / h
tanFov = tan(fov_y * 2.0) * 2.0;

size_x = ndx_size_x * z_eye * tanFov * aspect;
size_y = ndx_size_y * z_eye * tanFov;
```

Apply that to your code:

[image]

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

float cRadius = 10.0f;
float fov_y = 60.0f;
float nearp = 0.1f;
float farp = 500.0f;
float width = 500.0f;
float height = 500.0f;

void mouseMovement(int x, int y)
{
    int diffx = x - lastx; 
    int diffy = y - lasty; 
    lastx = x;
    lasty = y;

    float ndc_x = diffx * 2.0f / width;
    float ndc_y = diffy * 2.0f / height;

    float aspect = width / height;
    float fov_rad = fov_y * M_PI / 180.0;
    float tanFov = tan(fov_rad / 2.0);

    xtrans += ndc_x * cRadius * tanFov * aspect;
    ytrans -= ndc_y * cRadius * tanFov;
}

void mouseFunc( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
  lastx = x;
  lasty = y;
}
```

```cpp
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    width  = (float)w;
    height = (float)h;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov_y, width / height, nearp, farp);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

```cpp
void display(void)
{
    // [...]

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(xtrans, ytrans, -cRadius);
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    // [...]
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: That works Perfectly!. I have also added an if else statement to check left or right button click in both mouseFunc and mouseMovement. Now I have all my mouse button configured. LMB for rotating,RMB for panning and Mousewheel for zoom. Thanks again!!